# Java read String on batch

Tags: java, string, batch-file, program-entry-point, depends

I have a batch as follows:

```
@echo off
java Main 127.0.0.1
pause
```

Now I want the number after 'Main' in the code above to be a String, so that you can change the String by editing the batch file.

Comment: What will you do with that parameter ?

Comment: Why is it not a string now? I'm little confused.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the second line to read like `java Main %IP%` and IP to be a configuration variable at the top of the batch file?

Comment: It already is a String yes, but I want java to read the String. And I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
....
String IP_STRING=args[0];
....
}
```

Does this work?